# How to call another function in solidity that has a struct for a parameter of over 16 variables?

Tags: struct, stack

Let's say I have the following code:

```js
// This is in a separate imported interface.
interface MyInterface{
  struct MyStruct {
    uint256 one;
    uint256 two;
    // . . .
    uint256 sixteen;
  }
}

// This is in a separate contract
function doSomething(MyInterface.MyStruct a) public{
```

How could I `doSomething` from another contract? Right now, if I create a struct in my other contract:

```js
MyStruct patrickStruct = (one, two, three, ..., sixteen);
```

I will get:

```
Compiler run failed
CompilerError: Stack too deep when compiling inline assembly: Variable value0 is 2 slot(s) too deep inside the stack.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It works if the parameter is declared as memory `doSomething(MyInterface.MyStruct memory a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able set the variable in storage, even the whole struct as a variable, you'd have to set individual subsets of the variables into storage. This way they can be popped off the stack.